# Efficient way to convert Datetime array to x-ticks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of Javascript datetime objects which I would like to use as x-ticks for a bar graph. Being that default Datetime objects have a length > 50, I'm interested in shortening the strings. The way I'm shortening the strings would depend on the delta between DateTimes.
If the sequence was:
`['Wed Jul 21 2021 11:15:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)', 'Wed Jul 21 2021 12:15:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'...]` 
I would want `['Wed 11:15:40', 'Wed 12:15:40']`

But for: 
`['Thu Jul 22 2021 11:15:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)', 'Fri Jul 23 2021 12:15:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'...]` 
I would want `['Thu Jul 22, 21\'','Fri Jul 23, 21\'']`

Basically, I want to shorten datetimes to use them as tickers, what is an efficient way to handle this?

Comment: If you use major and minor ticks you could shorten these even more.  1st example the major might be `Wed` and minors of `11:15:40, 12:15:40`

Comment: I just realized I didn't specify the language.. I mean in Javscript

Comment: This is an interesting question, if a bit underspecified.  I don't have any immediate suggestions, *except*: most of the well known charting libraries must have already done this, so you might do well to look at their implementations.

Comment: Just seeing this. D3 has a way to do this.. well kinda. I ended up writing my own code to get it done